# Laravel Maatwebsite\Excel returns blank excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

i'm trying to create an excel from my laravel controller, what im trying to achieve is an excel file with 1 sheets named 'test' and add a value ("Heading") to A1 cell. but when i try to do it like this

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;


return Excel::download(function($excel) {

            // Create a new sheet and add the title
            $excel->sheet('test', function($sheet) {

                // Add the title
                $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Heading');

            });

        }, 'Custom Excel.xlsx');
```

it returns blank excel, it got the correct excel file name but not with the sheet name and that A1 value